# how to allow one method to be accessed by only refresh at a time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have one method which is called when ever i refresh my page and that method saves a value in the database.Now if i refresh the same page continuously 3-4 times then the value is stored 3-4 times in database. I want if i refresh it 3-4 times continuously then it should be called only the first time.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = confirmClose;

function confirmClose() {
  var refreshTime = new Date().getTime();
  if (!isNaN(keyerAudit.auditStartTime) && (keyerAudit.auditStartTime != 0))
    sessionStorage.setItem("FIRSTVISIT", refreshTime);
  var refreshAuditTime = 0;
  if (!isNaN(keyerAudit.auditStartTime) && (keyerAudit.auditStartTime != 0))
    refreshAuditTime = (refreshTime - keyerAudit.auditStartTime) / 1000.0;
  if (!isNaN(refreshAuditTime) && (refreshAuditTime != 0)) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("DB", refreshAuditTime);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/auditTimecalculate',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        auditTime: refreshAuditTime
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("returned from /auditTimecalculate ");
        console.log("the before refresh starttime was: ", keyerAudit.auditStartTime);
        sessionStorage.setItem("FIRSTVISIT", keyerAudit.auditStartTime);
        //                 refreshTime=undefined;
        refreshAuditTime = undefined;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You either need to make the request idempotent, or create a method of recording that the request has already been made - such as a flag in `localStorage`

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session variable like  `session["count"] = 1;`  on first refresh and then check its value inside the function if its 1 then execute otherwise dont.